# Doorkeeper is always showing the authorization page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I have an OAuth server build using Doorkeeper gem. I was so far [skipping application authorization](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Skipping-application-authorization) but need now to allow it.

The basic behavior is working and Doorkeeper is indeed showing me the authorization page including scope permissions:

[image]

However, everytime I logout and try to login again on the same application, it shows me **again** the authorization page. Is it the normal behavior or should the server detect that we accepted it already and should let us pass anyway?

I was thinking that I could play around with `skip_authorization` in order to check that manually but is there a better way?